# Error establishing a database connection on Installation

Tags: database, errors, installation, wp-config, configuration

I was working on my MacOS System with everything well configured and working. Now I try to migrate all of my work to Windows using the same software as in MacOS MAMP to run Wordpress on localhost. So I set up MAMP on my Windows System and copied all files from GitHub to my workstation on Windows.

The problem is, when I try to access to my Wordpress Project on my localhost, I get the error:

"Error establishing a database connection"

[image]

I can not even have `wp-config.php` file and I can't get it.

Searching for [similar](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/56623/error-establishing-a-database-connection-when-migrating-site-to-localhost) problems around here I have this [link](http://www.wpkube.com/how-to-fix-error-establishing-database-connection-in-wordpress/), but is not the same solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new file names wp-config.php and paste all the code than enter your db credentials it will solve your wp-config issue.

```
<?php
/**
 * The base configurations of the WordPress.
 *
 * This file has the following configurations: MySQL settings, Table Prefix,
 * Secret Keys, WordPress Language, and ABSPATH. You can find more information
 * by visiting {@link http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php Editing
 * wp-config.php} Codex page. You can get the MySQL settings from your web host.
 *
 * This file is used by the wp-config.php creation script during the
 * installation. You don't have to use the web site, you can just copy this file
 * to "wp-config.php" and fill in the values.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

// ** MySQL settings - You can get this info from your web host ** //
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define('DB_NAME', 'database_name_here');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'username_here');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'password_here');

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

/** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');

/** The Database Collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
define('DB_COLLATE', '');

/**#@+
 * Authentication Unique Keys and Salts.
 *
 * Change these to different unique phrases!
 * You can generate these using the {@link https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/ WordPress.org secret-key service}
 * You can change these at any point in time to invalidate all existing cookies. This will force all users to have to log in again.
 *
 * @since 2.6.0
 */
define('AUTH_KEY',         'put your unique phrase here');
define('SECURE_AUTH_KEY',  'put your unique phrase here');
define('LOGGED_IN_KEY',    'put your unique phrase here');
define('NONCE_KEY',        'put your unique phrase here');
define('AUTH_SALT',        'put your unique phrase here');
define('SECURE_AUTH_SALT', 'put your unique phrase here');
define('LOGGED_IN_SALT',   'put your unique phrase here');
define('NONCE_SALT',       'put your unique phrase here');

/**#@-*/

/**
 * WordPress Database Table prefix.
 *
 * You can have multiple installations in one database if you give each a unique
 * prefix. Only numbers, letters, and underscores please!
 */
$table_prefix  = 'wp_';

/**
 * For developers: WordPress debugging mode.
 *
 * Change this to true to enable the display of notices during development.
 * It is strongly recommended that plugin and theme developers use WP_DEBUG
 * in their development environments.
 */
define('WP_DEBUG', false);

/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */

/** Absolute path to the WordPress directory. */
if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
    define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');

/** Sets up WordPress vars and included files. */
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');
```

Comment: *Note:* With every downloaded - official source I assume - version of WordPress there comes the file `wp-config-sample.php` for this very reason. Filling in credentials and renaming it to `wp-config.php` is - under normal/standard circumstances - enough.

Comment: Not for me, I still get the error. But I really appreciate your effort, thank you.

Comment: may i know what version of wordpress you have ??

Comment: Yes, it's WordPress (Version 4.2.3).

Comment: can you share the database so that i can address the error because i sent you the 4.2.3 config code

Comment: do one thing reach your database and find these : define('AUTH_KEY',         'put your unique phrase here');
define('SECURE_AUTH_KEY',  'put your unique phrase here');
define('LOGGED_IN_KEY',    'put your unique phrase here');
define('NONCE_KEY',        'put your unique phrase here');
define('AUTH_SALT',        'put your unique phrase here');
define('SECURE_AUTH_SALT', 'put your unique phrase here');
define('LOGGED_IN_SALT',   'put your unique phrase here');
define('NONCE_SALT',       'put your unique phrase here'); and fill them in your wp-config file i wish this will definitely work

Comment: Don't work, again.

Comment: do you have remaining contents except wp-config i mean like all other files plus database ??

Comment: Yes, I am using Themes on wp-content. Is there a problem? Like I said, on MacOS everything is working fine.

Comment: install xampp or wamp on windows and than try installing it with the wp-config file i shared with you even i face this problem many times while switching from linux to windows i always received same issues with sql files or configuration file

Comment: XAPP and WAMP does not work again. I Think I have a `port` problem.

Comment: yes you are right try changing the port through xampp i wish this must help you

Comment: if port also does not help than repair your database or share with me through sqlfiddle

Comment: It's not the `port` I change it and nothing again. Thank you for your help, but I will give up and continue the work on MacOS.

Comment: oh okay i am so sorry that i couldn't help you to solve this error still if you need any help in future reach me at satishmehta768@yahoo.com good luck

Answer (score 1):

You need to create `wp-config.php` file. This new file is copy of `wp-config-sample.php` find it in root directory.

After creating this copy name it `wp-config.php` and set up database setting into it. Also give access permission to it.

Let me know if above wording is not used to for you.

Comment: It's the same solution above and does not work. But thank you for trying to help me.

Comment: You are getting the same error on both the front-end of the site, and the back-end of the site (wp-admin).

Comment: And what want you to conclude with that answer?

Comment: If the error message is the same on both pages "Error establishing a database connection", then proceed onto the next step. If you are getting a different error on the wp-admin for instance something like "One or more database tables are unavailable. The database may need to be repaired", then you need to repair your database.

Comment: You can do this by adding the following line in your wp-config.php file

Comment: define('WP_ALLOW_REPAIR', true);

Comment: Once you have done that, you can see the settings by visiting this page: http://www.yoursite.com/wp-admin/maint/repair.php

Comment: No. I give up, I will work on MacOS. Thank you for the help.